# find out which PC is ON over the network

Tags: windows, networking, cmd

I'm trying to find out which PCs are ON over the network, in order to alert users to shut down their PCs when they finish working. I tried `cmd msg` but it failed, I also tried to get systeminfo for all pc but getting only my pc systeminfo.

Is it possible to find out which PCs are on; or alternatively when the last time every PC shut down was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the IP-Adress of the Computers in your Network you should be able to ping them through the cmd window:

**ping [Insert Computer IP here]**

if you get a reply you know the computer is turned on.

Always remember **this will work only if the computers are on the same network**.